# Integral of the square root of a trigonmetric function

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

Despite my best attempts, I have been unable to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_s^t\sqrt{9+(2+\cos3u)^2}\,du.
$$
This integral showed up during an investigation of torus knots.  It represents the length of a subarc of the (1,3)-torus knot, which I've parametrized as
$$
\gamma_{1,3}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}(2+\cos 3t)\cos t\\(2+\cos3t)\sin t\\-\sin3t\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Is there any closed form for this integral?  I suspect that the answer is no, and a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523388/tight-approximation-of-a-torus-knot-length) lends evidence to this suspicion, but I couldn't find a statement anywhere to confirm this.

Comment: Nope. Maple writes the integral above in terms of Elliptic integrals.

Comment: There is a closed form but it is quite ugly !

Comment: You may try to mimic my derivation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/771296/73025). In your case the result should be of the same lexicographic complexity but with incomplete elliptic integrals instead of complete ones (because of more general integration bounds).